# Selenium Grid 2 - Chromedriver does not start a new profile on a new run

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While testing a website on Chrome using `selenium webdriver` (`chromedriver`) with `ruby` and `selenium grid 2`, I manually clicked on `Allow` to track my location.

Since then every new run starts off with the Chrome browser tracking my location and not asking for permission anymore.

In my understanding that should not happen, as Selenium should create a new profile and not remember any user interactions in the previous run.

I have also tried to open the Chrome Browser as an admin (manually) and change the settings to forget any permissions set for location services for the site being tested. But that has not helped either.

I have also tried to restart the grid but that has not helped either.

Does anyone know how do I make the browser forget my permission?

**UPDATE**

Code to start the driver

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => @sel_grid_url, :desired_capabilities => @browser)
```

Comment: How are you creating(initializing) the driver?

Comment: If you mean the selenium webdriver then yes.

Comment: I made an update to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new

data = profile.as_json

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['chromeOptions'] = {
  'profile'    => data['zip'],
  'extensions' => data['extensions']
}

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => @sel_grid_url, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Also verify that you have `Ask me when a site tries to track my physical location (recommended)` option checked, under `Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Location`.

**Update:**

Another try..

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = "/path/to/dir"
profile['profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation'] = 2 #Try 1 and 0 as well


data = profile.as_json

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['chromeOptions'] = {
  'profile'    => data['zip'],
  'extensions' => data['extensions']
}

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => @sel_grid_url, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Comment: So the problem is, any settings that I change (during the selenium run) do not get saved for the next run. Also the Chrome browser settings that I change manually, are not seen on the browser created by the script.

Comment: Tried your solution, and it does not clear the saved location

Comment: Will this http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=138 be of any help?

Comment: @amey- I think you can try using `ChromeOptions` as detailed there.

Comment: I am not sure how to translate it to `ruby`, any suggestions?

Comment: @vidit please give a doc link from where you got such chrome settings?

Comment: @RubyLovely - http://wiki.chromedriver.googlecode.com/git/CapabilitiesAndSwitches.wiki

Comment: @RubyLovely- Also this http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc, might be helpful.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I made edits to your answer only to display the necessary lines of codes. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a local WebDriver fix:

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :no_website_testing_defaults => true, :switches => %w[--disable-geolocation])
```

To do so remotely, I think it would probably look something like this:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(:no_website_testing_defaults => true, :switches => %w[--disable-geolocation])
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Please see the RubyBindings documentation for information on using switches https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Chrome

You can view a list of Chrome switches here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

**Update**

Looks like Chromedriver needs to turn testing defaults off first before some settings (like geolocation tracking) can be set (this according to a revision of the ChromeDriver Capabilities wiki found here: http://wiki.chromedriver.googlecode.com/git-history/c790ec6b0b32a31a8797a0fa97b7f4dccb4f5da4/CapabilitiesAndSwitches.wiki ).

I updated the code above to include the config to set to turn the testing defaults off (see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113884 and http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4622 ).

Please ensure that you are using selenium-webdriver 2.26.0 or greater.

Comment: based on the two links the code looks right. But unfortunately it doesn work.