# Custom profile for Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Environment: Mac OS X 10.8.3, Ruby 2.0.0p0, selenium-webdriver 2.32.1, ChromeDriver 26.0.1383.0.

I want to change default browser language. I am testing if the site detects the browser language correctly and displays the pages in the language.

I was able to set Firefox language to German:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new 
profile["intl.accept_languages"] = "de"

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(firefox_profile: profile) 
caps.platform = "Linux" 
caps.version = 20

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for( 
:remote, 
url: "http://USERNAME:ACCESS-KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub", 
desired_capabilities: caps)

driver.navigate.to "http://sandbox.translatewiki.net/"
```

I want to do the same using Chrome (and other browsers, if possible).

I have tried several things trying to open the page in German in Chrome, but every time the page is displayed in English, instead of in German.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new 
profile["intl.accept_languages"] = "de"

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(firefox_profile: profile) 
caps.platform = "Linux" 
caps.version = ""

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for( 
:remote, 
url: "http://USERNAME:ACCESS-KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub", 
desired_capabilities: caps)

driver.navigate.to "http://sandbox.translatewiki.net/"
```

If I change `firefox_profile: profile` to `profile: profile` or `chrome_profile: profile`, the page opens in English (instead of in German) every time.

As far as I can see in the [API docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Remote/Capabilities.html), only `:firefox_profile` is supported.

I was able to do it on a [local machine](http://filipin.eu/2013/04/19/chrome-profiles.html), but not when using Sauce Labs.

Comment: So, if you pass :firefox_profile to Chrome caps, it works or not?

Comment: @p0deje: It does not work. What ever I do, Chrome always opens the page in English, instead in German.

Comment: Are you sure that if you set your default language in your browser your page loads correctly?

Comment: Wrench -> Options -> Advanced -> Change Fonts and language settings -> Language -> Google Chrome language (select your language in the drop down menu) and accept

Comment: @fotanus: The question is about setting Chrome default language using Selenium and Ruby.

Comment: I got that, the question is if it works without Selenium. If you change the language in chrome and nothing it still not working, you will never make selenium work either, because it is basically this what it does.

Comment: @fotanus: I was able to change the language in both Firefox and Chrome using Ruby and Selenium on my machine. Please see the link at the end of the question. I was able to change language for remote Firefox, but not for remote Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new 
profile["intl.accept_languages"] = "de"

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  platform: "Linux", 
  version: "", 
  'chrome.profile' => profile.as_json['zip']
)

Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, 
  url: "http://...@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub", 
  desired_capabilities: caps
)
```

Comment: I knew Jari is the only one who can answer this question!

Comment: The best spent 500 reputation ever. :)

Comment: Has this been verified to work?  It seems so close to my proposed solution that it would surprise me if one worked and the other didnt.

Comment: would anyone know how to enable the flash plugin using the profile?

Comment: The 'chrome.profile' key didn't work for me, but setting up as this comment mentions is fine: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=338#c18

Answer (score 1):

Wow, the documentation for SauceLabs + Chrome + Selenium + Ruby is very inconsistent and sometimes contradictory.  Unfortunately I do not have a SauceLabs account to test so all I can do is give you suggestions.

[This documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) says it is a known issue that ChromeDriver does not support a custom profile.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025733/712765) shows how to set a custom profile for Chrome.  Go figure.

Setting a profile or a default language for that matter is NOT part of the standard [WebDriver wire protocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) so you may be out of luck.

One workaround would be to set your browser to use a proxy and in the proxy add/replace the Accept-Language header in the proxy.

Still, looking through the Selenium Ruby code, it looks like that post might be on to something, so give this a try:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile["intl.accept_languages"] = "de"

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['chromeOptions'] = { 'profile'    => profile.as_json['zip'] }
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for( 
:remote, 
url: "http://USERNAME:ACCESS-KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub", 
desired_capabilities: caps)

driver.navigate.to "http://sandbox.translatewiki.net/"
```

EDIT: It seems like the `--lang-` switch does not do what you want, so ignore the following.  I'm leaving it here for posterity.

This might work (forget about the profile, use command line switches):

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['chrome.switches'] = ['--lang-de']
```

Comment: Sauce Labs does have free accounts... :)

Comment: I could not find `--lang-de` switch at http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc Where did you find it?

Comment: I found the switch `--lang` + country code [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and [here](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/ui/base/ui_base_switches.cc). It may not work, but it's a possibility.  Have you tried contacting SauceLabs about this?  Really they should have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the German Translation on my local machine using:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile["intl.accept_languages"] = "de"
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :profile => profile  
@target = 'http://sandbox.translatewiki.net/'
```

osx: 10.7.5

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

Comment: Rich, as the last sentence in my question says, I am able to do it on a local machine (please notice link to my blog post), but not when using Sauce Labs.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can just use this method

```
  def launch_browser options={}

    language = options.fetch(:language, "en_US")
    url = options.fetch(:url, "www.google.com")

    prefs = {
        :intl => {
            :accept_languages => language
        }
    }
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs

    browser.goto url
  end
```

and then you just have to call

```
    launch_browser :language => "de"
```